# Xcode target copy files

Tags: ios, xcode

It's a "Cocoa Touch Framework" project whose project-name.framework file I wanna distribute but by default I want to generate the .framework file under bin folder (or is there any convention)

I don't wanna use absolute path as I'm sharing the project as well (open source)

question is, how can you specify a relative path to the location of project (bin folder inside the project)

Attached screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how can you specify a relative path to the location of project

The build takes place in the presence of environment variables. A good list is here:

https://gist.github.com/gdavis/6670468

So it sounds like you're looking for the `PROJECT_DIR` variable.

It sounds like you're not going to do this in the copy files build phase, though; you need to write your own script and do it in the run script build phase.

Comment: Can you please explain more, I tried copying pasting inside path field PROJECT_DIR, and destination as Absolute Path but I see nothing there once I click Run

Comment: got it, I had to use $(PROJECT_DIR)/bin